# Javascript remainder oper not working after first successive admob ad show

Tags: javascript, cordova, admob

I am trying to display Admob ads in app on if condition .if remainder of variable value == 0 then it should show Admob ad ,but its showing ad only one time and then doesn't show any ad .Some one help me where is the problem .

My Code is :

```
$('#next').click(function() {
    i++;
    if(i%10==0){
        if(AdMob)
               AdMob.showInterstitial();
    }

   $('#img').attr('src',images[a[i]]);
});
```

Comment: where is `i` declared?

Comment: all things are working fine but not showing the ads after one time

Comment: is it defined as a number, and is that particular `i` used elsewhere?

Comment: how big is the `images` array, how big and what values are in the `a` array ... there's more missing from this code than included

Comment: no its used in next button only

Comment: array length is 477